# Starting Index of a Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm doing a question where I need to find a general expression for the $a_n$ term in a series, and then find the "starting index of $n$".

I've found the general $a_n$, but I don't know what is meant by the "starting index of $n$"? I can't find any explanation or definition. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Can you give more details ?

Comment: We may represent a [Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29) either as $a_0 + \ldots$ or as $a_1 + \ldots$.

Comment: Most usually, the issue is : must we start at index $0$ or index $1$ ? For example series $\sum 1/n$ should start at index $n=1$.

Comment: May be meaning  $$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k$$